# Python functools partial callback arguements vs class properties within the callback methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, pika

This may simply be a basic python callback question but I am working with threads and a third party library, so excuse (and clarify) if I am mixing up different issues.

I'm looking at the [pika example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pika/pika/32de741f8d860982c6c8bc37d633ad78c16b630b/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) of implementing thread safe responses which uses a callback and `functools` partial as a way of passing additional arguments to the callback function.

```
def connect(self):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.connection.URLParameters(params)
    )
    channel = connection.channel()
    cb = partial(self._on_message, connection=connection) 
    channel.basic_consume(queue=queue, on_message_callback=cb)


def _on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body, connection):
    print(connection)
```

If I am using classes can I just set the additional arguments (in this case connection) as class properties if the property is only ever set once? Is the equivalent the same thing?

```
class MyClass:

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.connection.URLParameters(params)
        )
        channel = self.connection.channel()
        channel.basic_consume(queue=queue, on_message_callback=self._on_message)


    def _on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print(self.connection)
```

I think this is correct given that [the docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_consume) states the callback needs

```
The function to call when consuming with the signature on_message_callback(channel, method, properties, body)
```

Building on this, can I transform the `basic_ack` as per the example

```
def example():
    cb = functools.partial(ack_message, channel, delivery_tag)
    connection.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)

def ack_message(channel, delivery_tag):
    if channel.is_open:
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)
```

to become the following?

```
class MyClass

    def example(self):
        self.channel = channel
        self.delivery_tag = delivery_tag
        connection.add_callback_threadsafe(self.ack_message)

    def ack_message(self):
        if self.channel.is_open:
            self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag)
```

It doesn't look like an `ack_message` needs a particular parameter signature for `add_callback_threadsafe` to work.

Will my implementation with class properties and methods keep this implementation thread safe?

Comment: Why don't you want to follow the documentation examples? Have you done any testing on to see if your method works for the `on_message_callback`? How does the `pika` example using a partial for for `ack_message` keep the callback thread-safe?

Comment: I linked the examples in the question. I have a working implementation. I now want a class based implementation, hence the question.